# Changing the arrow tip size in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

Is there any way to change the size of the arrow tip in `tikz-cd`?  I have seen ways to change arrow tip size in `tikz`, but I haven't figured out how to apply it in `tikz-cd`.

Something I found when looking for something else is the following:

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}                   
\tikzcdset{every label/.append style = {font = \normalsize}}
```

This did successfully change the label font size.  I feel like there might be a way to use this, but I'm not sure what the syntax would be for arrow tips.

Comment: I would read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461 or/and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150721/.

Comment: Or maybe try `\arrow[scale=3]`

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I tried a bunch of combinations of suggestions in those posts, but I wasn't sure how to apply it in `tikz-cd`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include the arrow library needed for the type of arrows you want to use, like

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
```

and change the type of the tips using

```
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>= ... }}
```

(Replace the dots by the name of the tip.) For a list of available tips see the TikZ manual.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
% No tikzlibrary needed
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>=stealth}}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] & B \arrow[r, tail, two heads, dashed] & C\\
\end{tikzcd}

%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>=stealth'}}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] & B \arrow[r, tail, two heads, dashed] & C\\
\end{tikzcd}

%\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>={Computer Modern Rightarrow[width=8pt,length=3pt]}}}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] & B \arrow[r, tail, two heads, dashed] & C\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

One solution similar to the `\tikzcdset` in the question is

```
\tikzcdset{every arrow/.append style = -{Latex[scale=2.7]}}
```

using the `every arrow/.append style` syntax from this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286457/) and changing the size from this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161238/), substituting whichever arrow shape for `Latex`.